# Should I create Thumbnail of video in Web App (client-side) or Lambda/Server-side?

Tags: javascript, web-development, web-applications

I am trying to create a thumbnail from a video that I'll be uploading to my Web App(React). And then I'll upload that video to AWS S3, and thumbnail(image) to S3 as well.

**I wanted to know** where should I create the thumbnail from a video frame, either client-side or in a Lambda service?

I asked someone and they said to create thumbnail from video in Lambda function as it'll be a complex task and will need processing to do on client-side. But I don't think so as the code to create thumbnail is quite simple just create a canvas and convert it to an image.

Comment: If the client-side code is simple, can't you just write it and be done?

Comment: @DanWilson yeah I think so too, but the engineer with me said it'll be a take processing so shouldn't be done on client-side.

Comment: Should you burden everyone's devices with this computation?  Devices like phones or tablets where reduced power consumption is important?

Comment: You cannot trust that the thumbnail submitted with a video file has anything to do with that video file. Unless free form thumbnails are acceptable, do it server side as you can guarantee the result. Otherwise you have to verify the thumbnail, which is about as much work.